# Multiply each value in rows of Matrix A by each corresponding value of a specfic row in Matrix B

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a `A=[m,n]` matrix and a `B=[n,l]` matrix.

```
A =
[1     2     3   
 4     5     6   
 7     8     9   
 10    11    12]
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume `l=1`, so `B` is in fact a vector `B=[n,1]`

```
B =   [100    10     1]
```

I would like multiply all the values in each row of `A` by a corresponding value of `B` - column-wise.

I know how to do it "manually":

```
C=[A(:,1)*B(:,1), A(:,2)*B(:,2), A(:,3)*B(:,3)]
```

This is the result I want:

```
C = [100          20           3  
     400          50           6  
     700          80           9  
     1000         110          12]
```

Unfortunately my real life matrices are a bit bigger e.g. (`D=[888,1270]`) so I'm looking for smarter/faster way to do this.

Comment: What should be the output if l is not 1, i.e. if B is a matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Pre R2016b:

```
C=bsxfun(@times,A,B)

C =
     100          20           3
     400          50           6
     700          80           9
    1000         110          12
```

#### R2016b and later:

In MATLAB® R2016b and later, you can directly use operators instead of `bsxfun` , since the operators independently support implicit expansion of arrays.

```
C = A .* B
```

Answer (score 2):

If `I > 1`, then you will have to reorder the dimensions of `B` first with a `permute`,

```
>> B = [100 10 1; 1 10 100];
>> C = bsxfun(@times, A, permute(B, [3 2 1]));
>> C

C(:,:,1) =

         100          20           3
         400          50           6
         700          80           9
        1000         110          12


C(:,:,2) =

           1          20         300
           4          50         600
           7          80         900
          10         110        1200
```

Comment: +1 for the handling `I > 1`. By the way, this is in fact a faster version of `kron(A, B)`.